# Jenkins Perforce Plugin Not Checking Out Code From Perforce

Tags: jenkins, perforce

I am trying to create a jenkins job with perforce SCM.
Sonar Runner is used for analysis of the project which would give me execution success while analysing the project.

The problem is with perforce jenkins plugin which is not checking out code from perforce and hence sonar analysis is run without checking out code from perforce.

```
Started by user jones j alapat
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building on master in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\perforceSpringPOC\workspace
Using master perforce client: mar30
[workspace] $ "C:\Program Files\Perforce\p4.exe" workspace -o mar30
Changing P4 Client Root to: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\perforceSpringPOC\workspace
Saving modified client mar30
[workspace] $ "C:\Program Files\Perforce\p4.exe" -s client -i
Last build changeset: 42
[workspace] $ "C:\Program Files\Perforce\p4.exe" changes -s submitted -m 1 //mar30/...
[workspace] $ "C:\Program Files\Perforce\p4.exe" -s changes -s submitted //mar30/...@43,@42
Sync'ing workspace to changelist 42.
[workspace] $ "C:\Program Files\Perforce\p4.exe" -s sync //mar30/...@42
Sync complete, took 36 ms
[workspace] $ D:\softwares\sonar-runner-2.4\bin\sonar-runner.bat -Dsonar.jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver "-Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8" ******** ******** -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 ******** ******** "-Dsonar.projectBaseDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\perforceSpringPOC\workspace" -Dsonar.projectName=Mar30SpringMVCPOC -Dsonar.projectVersion=1.0 -Dsonar.projectKey=Mar30SpringMVCPOC -Dsonar.sources=.
D:\softwares\sonar-runner-2.4
SonarQube Runner 2.4
Java 1.8.0_11 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
Windows 8.1 6.3 amd64
INFO: Runner configuration file: D:\softwares\sonar-runner-2.4\conf\sonar-runner.properties
INFO: Project configuration file: NONE
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "windows-1252" (analysis is platform dependent)
INFO: Work directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\perforceSpringPOC\workspace\.sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 5.0
11:49:16.269 INFO  - Load global referentials...
11:49:16.398 INFO  - Load global referentials done: 129 ms
11:49:16.402 INFO  - User cache: C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.sonar\cache
11:49:16.408 INFO  - Install plugins
11:49:16.475 INFO  - Install JDBC driver
11:49:16.475 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
11:49:17.232 INFO  - Initializing Hibernate
11:49:18.094 ERROR - No license for plugin report
11:49:18.251 INFO  - Load project referentials...
11:49:19.123 INFO  - Load project referentials done: 872 ms
11:49:19.124 INFO  - Load project settings
11:49:19.459 INFO  - Loading technical debt model...
11:49:19.475 INFO  - Loading technical debt model done: 16 ms
11:49:19.475 INFO  - Apply project exclusions
11:49:19.590 WARN  - SCM provider autodetection failed. No SCM provider claims to support this project. Please use sonar.scm.provider to define SCM of your project.
11:49:19.605 INFO  - -------------  Scan Mar30SpringMVCPOC
11:49:19.609 INFO  - Load module settings
11:49:20.159 INFO  - Loading rules...
11:49:20.298 INFO  - Loading rules done: 139 ms
11:49:20.318 INFO  - Configure Maven plugins
11:49:20.372 INFO  - Compare to previous analysis (2015-03-30)
11:49:20.378 INFO  - Compare over 30 days (2015-02-28, analysis of 2015-03-30 11:37:50.0)
11:49:20.379 INFO  - No quality gate is configured.
11:49:20.475 INFO  - Base dir: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\perforceSpringPOC\workspace
11:49:20.475 INFO  - Working dir: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\perforceSpringPOC\workspace\.sonar
11:49:20.475 INFO  - Source paths: .
11:49:20.475 INFO  - Source encoding: windows-1252, default locale: en_US
11:49:20.475 INFO  - Index files
11:49:20.475 INFO  - 0 files indexed -------------------------No Files Are pulled from perforce
11:49:20.490 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor...
11:49:20.506 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor done: 16 ms
11:49:20.506 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor...
11:49:20.520 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor done: 13 ms
11:49:20.520 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor...
11:49:20.524 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor done: 4 ms
11:49:20.525 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor...
11:49:20.661 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor done: 136 ms
11:49:20.661 INFO  - Sensor FileHashSensor...
11:49:20.661 INFO  - Sensor FileHashSensor done: 0 ms
11:49:20.661 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor...
11:49:20.661 INFO  - No SCM system was detected. You can use the 'sonar.scm.provider' property to explicitly specify it.
11:49:20.661 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor done: 0 ms
11:49:20.661 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor...
11:49:20.661 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor done: 0 ms
11:49:20.742 INFO  - Execute decorators...
11:49:20.839 INFO  - Store results in database
11:49:21.043 INFO  - ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://localhost:9000/dashboard/index/Mar30SpringMVCPOC
11:49:21.043 INFO  - Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report.
11:49:21.043 INFO  - Executing post-job class org.sonar.issuesreport.ReportJob
11:49:21.044 INFO  - Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.issueassign.notification.SendIssueNotificationsPostJob
11:49:21.044 INFO  - Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.notification.SendIssueNotificationsPostJob
11:49:21.044 INFO  - Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.buildbreaker.AlertBreaker
11:49:21.060 INFO  - Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.buildbreaker.ForbiddenConfigurationBreaker
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 5.384s
Final Memory: 12M/183M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Notifying upstream projects of job completion
Finished: SUCCESS
```

As You Could see, the files from my perforce is not checked out .

My Configuration is given below

[image: Perforce jenkins plugin]

Comment: Can you try Clean workspace option from the Advanced settings in perforce section? Full wipe and then check Always force sync. This should resolve the problem.

Comment: I had done cleaning of workspace.

Comment: Anyway I got it working using p4 plugin

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like the 'p4 sync' command issued any errors.

Perhaps you had already run 'p4 sync' for those files in this workspace, but then you deleted those files from your workstation. In this case, since Perforce thinks you already have the files (it doesn't know that you removed them from your workstation), you'll have to run 'p4 sync -f' to get the files back onto your workstation.

Comment: But I have not deleted files from my workspace and all the files are present in workspace

Comment: If all the files are present in your workspace, what did you mean by "As You Could see, the files from my perforce is not checked out " in your question?

Comment: i ran an force sync still no effect.